# Apply a variable discount woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, rules, coupon, discount

I am using Woo Rules Pro but i cant find a solution with it
My Issue is that i have several products that have a regular and a sales price (example Product X1 regular price is 100 and now the discounted shop sales price is 70 so the discount is already 30%) ( Product X2 regular price is 50 and now the discounted shop sales price is 40, discount is 20%) and so on.
Problem:

1. I want to provide a coupon code "XXXX00" that is checking the sales price and discount of each item in the background and provide the discount amount which is 40% of the regular price, not more and not less.. Suppose I have Product X1 in my cart the coupon shall provide 10%  more discount the amount of the coupon that appears is 10, if i would have only the Product X2 in the cart then  the discount the code is providing shall be 40% in total and the amount of the coupon code is . If i have both in the cart the discount shall be also max 40% and the amount of the coupon is different. Hence the amount of the coupon is important as i have also to add it to total saving. but the percentage is 40% fix. Any idea how i can solve this?
2. On the other hand I have tried to create a coupon code with woo Rules pro plugin, and coupon it as a cart fee that shows at the end, problem the discounted amount does not calculate to the total saving. and the total saving shall be actually in this case only this amount as it shall ignore any other discounts, so the case is if the cart fee of woo Roles Pro is >0 then the total discount is equal the cart fee amount...

created coupon codes with Woo Rules Pro
tried different codes, nothing working